# how to add a label before a field based on condition

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

Hi  Is it possible to change string label base on condition

I have a kanban view , I want to add a string before the field

this is my xml code :

```
 <record id="res_partner_kanban_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Contact Kanban modification</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.res_partner_kanban_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="//t[@t-name='kanban-box']//div[@class='oe_kanban_details']//field[@name='display_name']">

  <label for="class_id" string="class : " attrs="{'invisible':['is_company','=',false)]}"/>

        <field name="class_id">
```

under the xpath i want to show a label like this "class :"
but with condition because i have many item on kanban view and i want just add this text to a student the string of label not displayed 
how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible. There is a nice example in Odoo V8 in the [invoice view definition](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9e8f70e4849b0eeaca8b5cf51372ecfa23dc561b/addons/account/account_invoice_view.xml#L141-L154)

```xml
<sheet string="Supplier Invoice">
    <div class="oe_title">
        <h1>
            <label string="Draft Invoice" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('state','&lt;&gt;','draft'), ('type','&lt;&gt;','in_invoice')]}"/>
            <label string="Draft Refund" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('state','&lt;&gt;','draft'), ('type','&lt;&gt;','in_refund')]}"/>
            <label string="Invoice" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('state', '=', 'draft'), ('type','&lt;&gt;','in_invoice')]}"/>
            <label string="Refund" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('state', '=', 'draft'), ('type','&lt;&gt;','in_refund')]}"/>
            <field name="number" class="oe_inline"  attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '=', 'draft')]}"/>
        </h1>
    </div>
```

As you can see, the label for field `number` is based on four conditions. All conditions use fields which are defined in the view itself. That is important!

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for solution to inherit view to change the label, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <!-- show custom field in form view -->
    <!-- inherit view "view_partner_form" -->
    <record id="view_partner_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <!-- name is whatever you like -->
        <field name="name">view.partner.inherit</field>
        <!-- this model field is the original model -->
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <!-- this inherit_id value is get by "external id" from debug mode view form -->
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='sales_purchases']//field[@name='user_id']" position="attributes">
                <!-- remove default label -->
                <attribute name="nolabel">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='sales_purchases']//field[@name='user_id']" position="before">
                <!-- set div, so it show in the same line -->
                <div>
                    <!-- add new label based on condition -->
                    <label string="Label 1" attrs="{'invisible':[('partner_id', '=', False)]}" for="user_id"/>
                    <label string="Label 2" attrs="{'invisible':[('partner_id', '!=', False)]}" for="user_id"/>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Hope it helped.